# Can't execute a file even after giving full permissions (in linux)

Tags: linux, gcc

I compiled my C code using `gcc` and it gave me a `.out` file. Now I am trying to execute the output file using terminal it keeps on showing me some error

> `fish: The file “./core.out” is not executable by this user`.

I am using fish shell - But I am getting same error on bash shell as well. I can't understand what could be the reason for this.

Command I used for `gcc`

> `gcc core.c -o core.out`

Output of `file core.out` is

> `core.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, > BuildID[sha1]=28e5ebcbdf1336774f74c7167a529a05af4e236b, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped`.

Error I am getting is:

[image]

Comment: The filesystem may have been mounted with the `noexec` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `noexec` option on the mounted partition. It's working fine and as expected after remounting. Thanks